# wordpress order by multiple

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a query in wordpress that looks like this,

```
 $args = array(  
        'post_type' => 'our-team',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => -1, 
        'orderby'           => array(
            'date_published' => 'ASC',
        )
    );
```

I am wanting to order my results by 2 attributes, firstly by date_published and then secondly my a meta value "weight". Weight is a numeric value (1 or 2).

When I change it the query to be,

```
$args = array(  
        'post_type' => 'our-team',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => -1, 
        'meta_key' => 'weight',
        'orderby'           => array(
            'date_published' => 'ASC',
            'meta_value' => 'ASC'
        )
    );
```

When I run this query it only returns posts that have a weight of 1?

Answer (score 0):

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'       => 'our-team',
    'posts_per_page'  => -1, 
    'post_status'     => 'publish',          
    'meta_key'        => 'weight',
    'orderby'         => array( 'meta_value_num' => 'ASC', 'post_date' => 'ASC' )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `date` instead of `date_published` i think `date_published` is not the right key. and weight should be in int so better to use `meta_value_num` instead of `meta_value` try the below code.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'       => 'our-team',
    'posts_per_page'  => -1, 
    'post_status'     => 'publish',          
    'meta_key'        => 'weight',
    'orderby'         => array( 
        'date'           => 'ASC' 
        'meta_value_num' => 'ASC'
    )
);
```